# Как сделать анимированный блюр/анблюр?

Tags: html, css

Стоит картинка. Когда на нёё наводишь, она разблюриваеться. НО с моим кодом блюр резко появляеться и пропадает. Как анимировать блюр? Вот мой код:

```css
.img {
filter: blur(8px);
}
.img:hover {
filter: none();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить `transition`

```css
.img {
  filter: blur(8px);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.img:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="https://westmetroeye.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/famliy.jpg">
```

Comment: А transition можно ли указывать там например filter 1s, а не all 1s?
Или override для других параметров?